# Is *arrayOf() a statement?

Tags: operators, kotlin

I was using the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs), when I noticed something strange:

```
// compiles
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, *(if(0 > 1) arrayOf(3) else arrayOf()))

// does not compile  
val list2 = listOf(1, 2, if(0 > 1) *arrayOf(3) else *arrayOf())
```

One of the compiler errors is

> Expecting an expression

- So, is `*arrayOf()` a statement?
- If yes, how can it be evaluated by `listOf()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's neither a statement nor expression.

The spread operator has a very special role: it can only modify the semantics of an array-typed expression passed as `vararg`, giving a special kind of argument. It cannot be used independently in other expressions, that's why the code where it's used inside an `if` expression does not compile.